# Avoid pushing node_modules everytime docker image is built

Tags: docker, node.js, docker-registry

So I have a NodeJS Project and I build the image every time there is a change and push it to our registry. Now the thing is I don't want to upload `node_modules` every time it pushes to registry, because it never changes, or more appropriately I only want to push the `node_modules` only if there is a change.

To take care of this I have put `node_modules` in its own volume but it still gets uploaded because, I think, the hash of the volume changes every time making it unique, even when there are no changes in packages. Is there a way out for this? I really do not want to re-upload files that are already in the registry.

Following is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
ENV PORT=5000
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /usr/app
VOLUME /usr/app/node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

**NB**: `npm i` and `npm ci` both cause new images to be pushed.

Comment: Did you try using a .gitignore file? Or a [dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file?

Comment: @CaldeiraG yep. My `dockerignore` includes the `node_modules`. I may have explained it improperly. The `npm ci` creates a `node_modules` in the image, i dont want it to upload if it doesn't change. I still might not be explaining it properly. Sorry for that.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934579/docker-ignore-is-not-woking-well-with-docker-compose-and-my-file-structure), looks very similar to your issue

Comment: @CaldeiraG yep checked that out, It uses `docker-compose`, not what i am looking for unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a solution, and it serves my need, might not be the best or a correct one.

I made two images, one with just `node_modules` and nothing else and the other one used that image as my base image for the project. This way, whenever there is a change in code, I can just push the second image to the registry and it will use the base image from the registry. If there is a change in the packages, I can update both the images.

This way I don't have to upload `node_modules` to registry every time.

**Implementation:**

```
# node_modules only
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package-lock.json .
COPY package.json .
RUN npm ci
```

```
# node code
FROM myregistry:project-nm:latest
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN ls
ENV PORT=5000
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

For anyone thinking, why did I have to do all this, it took way to long to upload the `node_modules` part of the image every time I made changes to the code. I had to upload around 70MB of `node_modules`, just to implement a change of few lines. This felt inefficient. So I looked for a solution.

Regards!